# Spring SAML creating new session on Service provider when returning from ID provider

Tags: spring, saml

I have a problem where a Spring boot application, when upgraded to Spring boot 2, fails to authenticate with SAML when running on a Linux VM. The same war file works on localhost. The previous version of the app also works on the Linux VM.

What happens, when I turn on debugging, I can see that a JSESSIONID cookie is set and a message is sent to the SAML ID provider. the SAML provider sends back a successful authentication, but Spring is looking for it in a new JSESSIONID that does not have it.

`DEBUG o.s.s.s.storage.HttpSessionStorage
                                - Storing message a217ja8287453ja5592818d0e46dija to session 41AAEE32192CF677032712FD544DB7AE`

...............
DEBUG o.s.s.s.storage.HttpSessionStorage
                                - Message a217ja8287453ja5592818d0e46dija not found in session 7805C108BACE3528EBEE7CA0D7DCCC9B

Any advice would be appreciated !

Answer (score 0):

It seems like a problem with the application. I suggest checking where in the code a new session (7805C108BACE3528EBEE7CA0D7DCCC9B) is being created. You can add HttpSessionListener and print a stack trace from sessionCreated method.

Check that the browser sends a correct cookie with JSESSIONID after successful authentication with SAML server and redirection back to the browser.

Comment: Thanks, how do I get a stack trace to print when that method is called? I can see how to register the HttpSessionListener and I expect it will be calling the sessionCreated() method.

Comment: Something like this should priint a stack trace into your log. logger.error("sessionCreated", new Exception("Stack trace"));

Comment: actually I'm remote debugging it on the server now, and it seems it is creating sessions repeatedly and they are then becoming null, if I understand what's happening. It doesn't seem to be calling sessionDestroyed though. need to figure out what is causing the session to become null.

Comment: Doh! The app was running on http, not https, with the property server.servlet.session.cookie.secure set to true. Spring boot 2 reacts to that property by rejecting JSESSIONID cookies over http. Didn't have that property on my local box, and the Spring boot 1 version doesn't know that property (knows it by another name).  Thanks user 1206747 you got me looking in the right places.